WhatsApp API Webhook Not Receiving Message Webhooks - all other webhooks works well
I'm experiencing an issue with WhatsApp webhook messages events not being triggered, despite other webhook tests working correctly (like flows \ security \ account_alerts.
Environment:

Using WhatsApp Business API
Tested on Facebook's webhook test page
Facebook app in Live mode

Problem Details:

All webhook tests received successfully EXCEPT message webhooks
No webhooks are triggered when:

Sending messages from the Facebook webhook test page
Sending messages directly to the registered WhatsApp number



Code/Configuration Attempts:
// Simplified webhook handler (example)
app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {
  const body = req.body;
  console.log('Webhook received:', body);
  
  if (body.entry && body.entry[0].changes) {
    // Webhook processing logic
  }
  
  res.sendStatus(200);
});


You have subscribed to get messages? You can allow in panel if it's the first WhatsApp Number:

Or you need to use API if was not the first added number:
POST to https://graph.facebook.com/v21.0/{{PHONE_NUMBER_ID}}/subscribed_apps with your bearer and this payload:
{
    "data": ["messages"]
}


Wow! I could not guess that clicking subscribe is valid only for the first number! And I see no reason for the test to work only if you subscribes (all the other test buttons works without subscription)
Thanks a lot

The Meta API is just bad. Your welcome
